# How to implement a SplitDateTImeWidget for a DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am subclassing a `ModelForm` and changing the default widget for the `DateTimeField`:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields[field_name]
            if isinstance(field, formfields.DateTimeField):
                field.widget = SplitDateTimeWidget()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = fields = '__all__'
```

The `View` is very simle:

```
class CustomCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'

    def get_form_class(self):
        form_class = CustomModelForm
        return form_class
```

However, this results in the following error when the form is processed:

> AttributeError at /lists/event/create 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

I know it's related to the `SplitDateTimeWidget()` but can't figure out why. If I apply the widget the standard way on a 1-1 basis with named fields via Meta, I still get this error.

Where should I start looking to debug?

**Update**

I think I've narrowed down the error to `SplitDateTimeWidget` has to use `forms.SplitDateTimeField` not the default `forms.DateTimeField` that's inherited from `models.DateTimeField` (per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeField.))

However I am not sure how I would set the field type in this loop? `field = forms.SplitDateTimeField()` does not apply the field type.

Comment: can you show the full error trace? And show the value you're submitting (`request.POST` in your `CreateView`), you'll need to add the `post()` method, just override it and `return super().post(...)` so you can set a breakpoint or print.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the error to `SplitDateTimeWidget` has to use `forms.SplitDateTimeField` not the default `forms.DateTimeField` that's inherited from `models.DateTimeField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeField. Do you know how I can set this in the for loop for all the fields?

Comment: You replace it: `self.fields[field_name] = SplitDateTimeField()`